# Sending a message to a TestProbe() fails sometimes with ActorInitializationException

Tags: scala, akka

I've some sporadic test failures and struggle to figure out why. I have a bunch of actors which to the work which I want to test. At the beginning of the test I pass in an actor reference which I get from a TestProbe(). Later on the group of actors do some work and send the result to the given test probe actor reference. Then I check the result with the TestProbe():

```
class MyCaseSpec extends Spec with ShouldMatchers{
    describe("The Thingy"){
        it("should work"){
            val eventListener = TestProbe()

            val myStuffUnderTest = Actor.actorOf(new ComplexActor(eventListener.ref)).start();
            myStuffUnderTest ! "Start"

            val eventMessage = eventListener.receiveOne(10.seconds).asInstanceOf[SomeEventMessage]
            eventMessage.data should be ("Result")
        }

    }
}
```

Now once in a while the test fails. And when I look through the stack trace I see that I got a 'ActorInitializationException' when sending a message to the test probe actor. However at no point in time I stop the TestProbe actor.

Here's the exception:

```
[akka:event-driven:dispatcher:global-11] [LocalActorRef] Actor has not been started, you need to invoke 'actor.start()' before using it
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: Actor has not been started, you need to invoke 'actor.start()' before using it
[Gamlor-Laptop_c15fdca0-219e-11e1-9579-001b7744104e]
at akka.actor.ScalaActorRef$class.$bang(ActorRef.scala:1399)
at akka.actor.LocalActorRef.$bang(ActorRef.scala:605)
at akka.mobile.client.RemoteMessaging$RemoteMessagingSupervision$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(RemoteMessaging.scala:125)
at akka.mobile.client.RemoteMessaging$RemoteMessagingSupervision$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(RemoteMessaging.scala:121)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:545)
....
```

I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious or am I making a subtle mistake? Or maybe something is really going wrong inside my code and I can't see it?

I'm on Akka 1.2.

Update for Vitors-Comment. At line 125 I send a message to an actor with the !-operator. Now in the test-setup thats the TestProbe actor-reference. And I can't figure out why sometimes the TestProbe actor seems to be stopped.

```
   protected def receive = {
      case msg: MaximumNumberOfRestartsWithinTimeRangeReached => {
        val lastException = msg.getLastExceptionCausingRestart
        faultHandling ! ConnectionError(lastException, messages.toList, self) // < Line 125. The faultHandling is the TestProbe actor
        become({
            // Change to failure-state behavior
          }
    // Snip
```

Anyway, I'm trying to isolate the problem further for the time being. Thanks for any hint / idea.

Comment: Why haven't you included the most interesting section? at akka.mobile.client.RemoteMessaging$RemoteMessagingSupervision$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(RemoteMessaging.scala:125)

Comment: At 125 I send a message to my TestProbe() actor: I can't figure out why the test-probe actor is not running sometimes and I get the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, almost certainly found the issue =). TestProbes do have a timeout: When nothing happens after 5 seconds, they stop them self.

Now unfortunately the test takes just a little longer than 5 seconds: In that time the test-probe may stop itself all ready, which then causes the test to fail.

Fixing it is easy, increase the timeout on the TestProbe:

```
  val errorHandler = ignoreConnectionMsgProbe()
  errorHandler.setTestActorTimeout(20.seconds)
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what happens and the way to deal with it (you may also completely disable it using `Duration.Inf`). I also found that confusing (cost me some hours to blame the actual cause a few weeks back), and I should have known. Anyway, the issue is gone in 2.0, where all actors are orderly shutdown after the test without any timeouts (if you stop the ActorSystem, that is).

Answer (score 1):

You are not starting your actor here. I'm not sure why your test is working some of the time. The code above needs to have the following line modified with an `.start()`

```
val myStuffUnderTest = Actor.actorOf(new ComplexActor(eventListener.ref)).start();
```

Comment: Oh. That's a mistake in the example above. In the actual test it is started. Fixed the example.